# How to change the body background with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For an assignment at school I need to make the background of my body change into the background of whatever button (div) I click on.

I don't get what I'm doing wrong here. Don't I have to use querySelector() and then add .style.backgroundImage to make it change?

```js
function btnClick() {
  var bgImg = document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = "url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/86/dd/86ddabfea12cf403e6a7e5850f272cc9.jpg)"; 
    // was url(../img/img1.png)
}
```

```css
.Btn {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
}

.Btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Btn1 {
  background-image: url(https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/86/dd/86ddabfea12cf403e6a7e5850f272cc9.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Btn" onclick="btnClick ()" id="Btn1"></div>
```

Comment: looks like its working alright

Comment: you can simply do document.body

Comment: Your code works when I use a real image that exists. Look in your console in the network tab to see the 404 you likely have

Comment: @mplungjan you make it working :p .. probably the issue was the image path

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: The code indeed seems to work for the with the url that @mplungjan's url. The problem is with my images on the computer I guess. Whenever I link them with the path on my mac than it doesn't work anymore.